# The force exerted on a magnetic dipole $m$ in magnetic field $B$

Tags: electromagnetism

How can one prove that:

The force exerted on a magnetic dipole $m$ in magnetic field $B$, in addition to $F=\nabla(m\cdot B)$, can be expressed by

$$F=(m\times \nabla)\times B.$$

Comment: I'm confused by the question.  Are you aware that those two expressions hold in different contexts?  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment#Force_on_a_moment

Comment: The net force on a magnetic dipole in a magnetic field is $0$, because there will be equal and opposite forces on the north and south poles. There *is* a torque created, though. Are you sure you haven't muddled the formulae up?

Comment: @joshphysics I admit that reading that page I got confused too, however the proof seems to be very straightforward. To be sure I have also checked the identity I used below ($(A\times \nabla) \times B =...$)

Comment: No it's OK. The Wiki page uses $m\times (\nabla \times B)$ and not $(m \times \nabla)\times B$ as in the OP's question.

Comment: @V.Moretti Ah! Ok good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In view of a known identity concerning the cross  product:
$$(m\times \nabla)\times B = \nabla (m\cdot B)- m (\nabla \cdot B) = \nabla (m\cdot B) = F$$
because $\nabla \cdot B=0$.